# How to pass from mvc to angular 2 and type script?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript

I need some help.I am new to angular. What i want is to pass some data (string variable 'element') to my UI and then I want to use it. I do not know how to pass it inside main.js and further. How can I pass variable to typescript file from my mvc server?
Index.cshtml:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<app-root>Loading...</app-root>
```

My layout file:

```
 @{
var elementServer = CamComponentGenerator.Api.App.elementID;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - Cam Component Generator for Onshape</title>
<script src="~/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('../ngapp/.compiled/main.js').catch(function (err)
    {
        console.error(err);
    });
</script>
<script>
    var element = "@elementServer";
</script>
  @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
@RenderBody()
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/ccg-script.js")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

My main.ts file:

```
 import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
 import { AppModule } from './app.module';
 const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
 platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

and my app.ts file:

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ParamsComponent } from './app/ccg-disk-cam-params/disk-cam-
 params.component';
import { CenterComponent } from './app/ccg-center/ccg-center.component';
import { ResultsComponent } from './app/ccg-results/ccg-results.component';
import { OutputComponent } from './app/ccg-output/ccg-output.component';
import { CylinderTranslatingComponent } from './app/ccg-disk-cam-follower-
params/cylinder-translating.component';
import { CylinderSwingingArmComponent } from './app/ccg-disk-cam-follower-
params/cylinder-swinging-arm.component';
import { SphereTranslatingComponent } from './app/ccg-disk-cam-follower-
params/sphere-translating.component';
import { SphereSwingingArmComponent } from './app/ccg-disk-cam-follower-
params/sphere-swinging-arm.component';
import { ModalComponent } from './app/ccg-modal/ccg-modal.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';


@NgModule({
 imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, FormsModule ],
 declarations:
 [
    AppComponent,
    ParamsComponent,
    CenterComponent,
    ResultsComponent,
    OutputComponent,
    CylinderTranslatingComponent,
    CylinderSwingingArmComponent,
    SphereSwingingArmComponent,
    SphereTranslatingComponent,
    ModalComponent
],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: where do you want to use it on the angular side?

Comment: The best scenario - in any ccg-.....ts file inside app directory.

Comment: Expose a Get method on your MVC application and make a Http request from Angular to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global javascript variable, or you can use local storage.

**GlobalVariable:**

Before boostrapping angular:

```
<script>
        var element = "@elementServer";    
        var globalVariable = element;            
</script>
```

When you need to use the variable in your component declare is as any:

> declare var globalVariable: any;

And you can then use it:

```
var myGlobal = globalVariable;
```

**Using LocalStorage:**

This is more of a workaround that I've used before. You can pass the razor variable to javascript as you are doing, then save it in localStorage. Then you angular components can retrieve the value from localStorage.

Both these approaches are **not** recommended for sensitive data.

So before you bootstrap angular2:

```
<script>
    var element = "@elementServer";    
    localStorage.setItem('elementServer',element);
</script>
```

then you can retrieve the item in your angular component:

```
var lstorage = localStorage.getItem("elementServer");
```

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/6GVhqWUDD2yAT5QAWmwh)